# Cannot import my own dependencies in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I have created utils.py and constant.py (saved in the same folder of all src file) and I wrote this in main.py

```
import utils
import constant
```

but when I try to run the entire program it gives me this error:

> Unable to import 'utils'

and if I open utils.py I noticed this error:

> Unable to import 'constant'

(because I need constant also in utils.py)

How can I solve it?

Comment: do you have an \_\_init\_\_.py file in your dir?

Comment: @user2717954 yes

Comment: are your files in the same directory?

Comment: @AhmadMoussa yes I put them in ./src folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this
 `from . import utils`
and have a look at this [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

try this one:

```
import sys

sys.path.append("<path/to/project>")

import utils
```

Or

`from .utils import *`

Comment: It give me this error: from . import utils 
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Same problem :/

Comment: Can you share tree structure of src folder?

Comment: and where is `main.py` where you are trying to import.

Comment: my `main.py` is `TikTokTool.py`

Comment: try `from .utils import *`

Comment: it doesn't work, now is full of "Undefined variable"

Comment: restart your IDE

Comment: done but same error: from .utils import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Create a completely new folder and try to do the same with basic funtions (e.g just a function that prints something). Import that from another file in the directory. If that fails then the issue is in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of importing functions from another file is done like this:

```
from file_name import function_name
```

If you want to import everything you should do this:

```
from file_name import *
```

Comment: I tried this one but it says " Unable to import 'utils' "